# memory leak while using toString()

Tags: java

Does converting to a string(i.e .toString() ) consumes lots of memory or even leads to memory leak?If yes.then is there any way to handle this? I think when i  am parsing pdf text to simple text my program is consuming lot of memory, dont know if this is the reason.

**PS: I am using itext to parse the pdf**

Comment: Define "lots of memory".

Comment: lots of memory as in memory leakage may be

Comment: What happens when you call System.gc()? Does it free up memory? What if you call your methods again and then call System.gc() again?

Comment: @raghav That doesn't help at all.

Comment: no it doesn't free up memory and memory leakage occurs when the pdf is large.

Comment: I believe the problem is not the toString method(unless you have overriden them and use some data structure you never empty). If you post your code, maybe we can see what is going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a large pdf, then yes it does consume a lot of memory. The only solution i can see is divide you pdf into smaller ones and then run your operations on each one. Finally, regroup the results

**UPDATE :**

While googling, I found that you CAN split pdf using itext library, check these links:

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/06/itext-tutorial-merge-split-pdf-files-using-itext-jar.html

http://sanjaal.com/java/448/java-pdf/splitting-pdf-file-using-java-itext-api-into-multiple-pdfs/

Comment: I dont think itext library allows this procedure

Comment: @raghav I never tried with itext but certainly you can split the pdf using normal java operations.

Comment: @raghav if this answer helps you, please check it

Answer (score 1):

converting somethifn to string usually requires allocation of new string objects (and this consumes memory).   whether this constitutes memory leak depends on implementation  of toString() methods. Usually there are no memory leaks though.

Answer (score 1):

Dont use itext for converting your pdf into string. If you would like to extract text from a pdf use the apache pdfbox library. Itext wasn't meant for this purpose although it does it.

Here's some code that will get you started..

```
public static String pdftoText(File file) {
    PDFParser parser=null;
    String parsedText = null;
    PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = null;
    PDDocument pdDoc = null;
    COSDocument cosDoc = null;
    try {
        parser = new PDFParser(new FileInputStream(file));
        parser.parse();
        cosDoc = parser.getDocument();
        pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
        pdDoc = new PDDocument(cosDoc);
        parsedText = pdfStripper.getText(pdDoc);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // handle exception
    } finally {
        try {
            if (cosDoc != null)
                cosDoc.close();
            if (pdDoc != null)
                pdDoc.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // handle excpetion
        }
    }
    return parsedText;
}
```

I dont what it would do to your memory situation.. Try this out and see if it helps. The URL is here:

http://pdfbox.apache.org/index.html